# how to detect if javascript is disabled in xhtml

Tags: javascript, redirect, noscript

I have an xhtml website delivered with the suitable xhtml header ('Content-type: application/xhtml+xml'), so it is treated as an xml document. The page relies heavily on Javascript and I want to implement a redirect if Javascript is disabled or errors occur.

the

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=http://www.google.com' />
</noscript>
```

approach does not work because the refresh is always triggered since `<noscript>` »cannot be used in xml documents«, that is what the spec says. But how can I manage the redirection else?

Comment: How about you redirect when JavaScript is enabled?

Comment: that implies a lot of serverside work

Comment: because on the page is a lot going with namespaced xpath, what does not work without the xhtml header.